# How do I avoid referring to all state variables when updating only a few?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

An idiom I use for composing a couple of procedures (with memory) is as follows:

```
p1 :: State (Int, String) ()
p1 = do
    (a, b) <- get
    ... do something ...
    put (a', b)

p2 :: State (Int, String) ()
p2 = do
    (a, b) <- get
    ... do something else ...
    put (a, b')

main = do
    ... initializing a0 b0 ...
    print . flip evalState (a0, b0)
          . sequence $ replicate 10 p1 ++ repeat p2
```

However, as the number of state variable grows, this quickly gets way more verbose than necessary:

```
p1 :: State (Int, String, Bool, Int, String, Bool) ()
p1 = do
    (a, b, c, d, e, f) <- get
    ... do something ...
    put (a, b, c', d, e, f')

p2 :: State (Int, String, Bool, Int, String, Bool) ()
p2 = do
    (a, b, c, d, e, f) <- get
    ... do something ...
    put (a', b', c, d, e, f)

main = do
    print . flip evalState (a0, b0, c0, d0, e0, f0)
          . sequence $ replicate 10 p1 ++ repeat p2
```

As I was wondering, is there a way of updating only a few state variables without having to refer to all the unused ones? I was thinking something like `IORef` but for `State` (in fact there is a package [stateref](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stateref)), but I'm not sure if there are already some common idioms that other people have been using.

Comment: I kind of feel that in this case the record syntax might be better suited. So something like `State MyState ()` where `data MyState = MyState { a :: Int, b :: String, c :: Bool, ... }`.

Comment: So if only `a` is update, I can just write `put $ myState {a = a'}`.

Comment: you might also like using the `RecordWildCards` extension with your new `MyState` type

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems like a job for [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). Especially the [`Control.Lens.Tuple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html) module together with `.=` and `use`:

```
p1 = do
   a <- use _1
   -- do something --
   _1 .= a'
```

However, it's usually better if you give the things in your state proper names, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-

data Record = MkRecord { _age :: Int
                       , _name :: String
                       , _programmer :: Bool
                       } deriving (Show, Eq)
makeLenses ''Record
```

That way, you have better names for your field:

```
p1 = do
   a <- use age
   -- do something --
   age .= a'
```

Note that this still helps you if you don't want to use lenses, since you can use record syntax to update your data:

```
 p1 = do
      r <- get
      let a = _age r
      --- do something
      put $ r{_age = a'}
```

Comment: In this context, perhaps it is worth mentioning `zoom` from *lens* as well.

Answer (score 11):

This is a good situation to use records, with the `gets` and `modify` functions to manipulate subparts of the state:

```
data Env = Env
  { envNumber :: Int
  , envText :: String
  }

p1 :: State Env ()
p1 = do
    a <- gets envNumber
    -- ...
    modify $ \r -> r { envNumber = a' }

p2 :: State Env ()
p2 = do
    b <- gets envText
    -- ...
    modify $ \r -> r { envText = b' }
```

`gets` turns a pure getter function into a state action:

```
gets :: (s -> a) -> State s a
envNumber :: Env -> Int
gets envNumber :: State Env Int
```

And `modify` turns a pure update function into a state action:

```
modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
(\r -> r { envText = b' }) :: Env -> Env
modify (\r -> ...) :: State Env ()
```

Answer (score 5):

`lens`'s [`zoom` combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom) lifts a computation in a `State` monad into a computation that runs in a "larger" `State` monad.

```
zoom :: Lens' s t -> State t a -> State s a
```

So, given a "big" state:

```
data Big = Big {
    _big1 :: Medium,
    _big2 :: Medium
}
data Medium = Medium {
    _medium1 :: Small,
    _medium2 :: Small
}
data Small = Small { _small :: Int }

makeLenses ''Big
makeLenses ''Medium
makeLenses ''Small
```

you can "zoom in" on a part of the state:

```
incr :: State Int ()
incr = id += 1

incrSmall :: State Big ()
incrSmall = zoom (big2.medium1.small) incr
```

Of course, this'll work on big tuples as well as records, using `lens`'s built-in [tuple field accessors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html).

`zoom`'s real type signature is more general than the simple one I quoted above. It uses `MonadState` constraints to work under a monad transformer stack, rather than in `State` specifically.